# Fed Ex Rate Service

Tags: c#, soap, rate, fedex

I have downloaded the C# Rate Service example code from Fed Ex's Developer Resource Center.  I edited the code with my test key and password  The project builds OK, but it keeps looking for a settings file that doesn't exist in the example code and is not referenced in the documentation.

```
private static String getProperty(String propertyname) //Sets common properties for testing purposes.
    {
        try
        {
            String filename = "C:\\filepath\\filename.txt";
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(filename))
            {
                System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(filename);
                do
                {
                    String[] parts = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
                    if (parts[0].Equals(propertyname) && parts.Length == 2)
                    {
                        return parts[1];
                    }
                }
                while (!sr.EndOfStream);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Property {0} set to default 'XXX'", propertyname);
            return "XXX";
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Property {0} set to default 'XXX'", propertyname);
            return "XXX";
        }
    }
```

I have been trying to guess what the file should look like, without any luck.  As nearly as I can tell it should be simple text file.  Has anyone else gotten this to work?

I have followed the comments in the code and added my developer key and password, but I get the following response:

Notification no. 0
 Severity: ERROR
 Code: 1000
 Message: Authenticatio
 Source: prof

Answer (score 0):

I know how to solve this issue.
Just create a file called filename.txt to the given folder that is "C:\filepath\filename.txt"

[See FilePath Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inIka.png)

and write your key and password in this file that you got from FedEx for testing purpose.
[See File Content Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syymE.png)

That's it try again to run your application this time you didn't face file doesn't exist issue.

I hope this will gonna help you...